How to check if $f(x) = |x|\sqrt{|x|}$ is strictly convex?
In this question: Question, it was mentioned that the function $f(x) = |x|^{3/2}$ is strictly convex but not strongly convex. Graphing the function allows us to see that it is indeed the case:

I now attempt to check the strict convexity of this function via the first-order characterization. Specifically, I aim to prove that
$$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, \quad |y|^{3/2} \ge |x|^{3/2} + \frac{3}{2} |x|^{1/2} (y - x). \mathrm{sgn}(x),$$
where $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ is the sign of $x$, defined by $\mathrm{sgn}(x) = 1$ when $x > 0$, $\mathrm{sgn}(x) = -1$ when $x < 0$ and $\mathrm{sgn}(x) = 0$ when $x = 0$.
My question is, is there an elegant way to verify this inequality? I attempted to use brute force (splitting into cases like $x > y > 0$, $y > x > 0$, $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, and so on, and was not satisfied with the solution I achieved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Based on geetha290krm's comment, indeed it is very easy to verify that the function $f'(x) = \mathrm{sgn}(x)\sqrt{|x|}$ is strictly increasing on two intervals $(-\infty , 0]$ abd $[0, +\infty )$ so it is strictly increasing on the entire real number line.

It is much easier to check the $f'$ is strictly increasing.

Thanks for suggesting, but I think it does not contain the answer to my question. I orginally cited that same question in my post.

Let's prove even more general fact: if $p\in\mathbb R, p\ge1$, then
$f(x)=|x|^p$ is convex everywhere in $\mathbb R$.
We will check it using convex fucntion definition. Let me remind it:
$$
f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y) \le \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y), \:\alpha\in[0,1]
$$
We rewrite the left hand side of it using $f(x)=|x|^p$:
$$
|\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y|^p\le\{\text{use triangle inequality}\}\le
\left|\alpha|x|+(1-\alpha)|y|\right|^p=
$$
$$
=\left|\left[|\alpha x|^{p}\right]^{\frac 1p} + \left[|(1-\alpha) y|^{p}\right]^{\frac 1p}\right|^p\le \{\text{use Minkowski inequality\}}\le
$$
$$
\le|\alpha x|^p+|(1-\alpha)y|^p\le \alpha^p |x|^p+(1-\alpha)^p|y|^p\le
\{\alpha \in[0,1]\}\le
$$
$$
\le\alpha|x|^p+(1-\alpha)|y|^p
$$
You can see that $p\ge 1$ condition makes it possible to use Minkowski inequality that is actually triangle inequality for $p$-norms.
